# JQuery accordion not working with Javascript created content

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, accordion

I am looking to use a form to add items to an array in Javascript and then use he values to be displayed in accordion.

However, when I create a string of the values and add them to the HTML file, the accordion doesn't work. It is in exactly the same format when it is added than when it is entered manually.

When I enter the same code manually, the accordion works no problem

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Code to create string:

```
contact.prototype.contactList= function(){
var cl = "<h3>" + this.firstname + "</h3><div><p>" +
         this.middlename + "" + this.lastname + "" + this.homeadd1 + ""+ this.homeadd2 + ""+ this.homeadd3 + ""+ this.homepost + ""+ this.workadd1 + ""+ this.workadd2 + ""+ this.workadd3 + ""+ this.workpost + ""+ this.email + ""+ this.homephone + ""+ this.workphone +""+ this.mobilephone +""+ this.dob +""+ this.relstat +"</p></div>";

return cl;
```

};

JS Accordion Function:

```
$('#accordion').on('update', 'h3', function() {
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
        });
```

The id I am adding the content to is called accordion

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: please explain what you expect code shown to do. We can't see where you create accordion from string and you haven't shown any code for any event `update`. A demo in jsfiddle.net would help

Comment: I dont create the accordion from string, i thought that was included in JQuery. I don't have an update event either - i thought it also was included. I can't provide a JSFiddle as I can't get it to work but here is what I am trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/wdy8z/2/ using this as an example :http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ Thanks

Comment: In that case it's really not clear what your first function is for. Show how you are currently using it. To be honest I think you need to start from a higher level explaining your overall goals as it pertains to converting data to accordion

Answer (score 0):

Check API of jqueryui.

Maybe you need to use refresh.

http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-refresh